# Usign Heroku without using toolbelt

Tags: heroku, heroku-connect

I want to use heroku without using Heroku toolkit as there are some admin related issues.

How can I use the Heroku platform with installing any other application, is there a way to create the apps or perform commits and run with out the toolkit.

Also if anyone is having any idea if Heroku can be used freely in enterprise machines as well without any restriction.

Thanks,

Ray

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a way. Eclipse!

You can use eclipse plugin to perform deployment and other admin related things.

Heroku Plugin URL: [Heroku Install](https://eclipse-plugin.herokuapp.com/install)
More information is given at: [Official Heroku Help](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-java-applications-to-heroku-from-eclipse-or-intellij-idea#deploying-from-eclipse)

Before these, you must have:
- E-GIT plugin in eclipse
- Eclipse version 3.7 or later

Read More: [Official Getting Started on Eclipse](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-heroku-eclipse)